# как скачать музыку, которую пользователь прислал?

Tags: python, aiogram

юзер шлёт боту музыку, а он скачивает её на пк и отправляет юзеру обратно

Как реализовать такую функцию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте метод [download_file](https://dev-docs.aiogram.dev/api/download_file/).

Накидал пример по спеке:

```
file_id = message.voice.file_id
file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
file_path = file.file_path
await bot.download_file(file_path, "123.mp3")
```

Comment: при попытке скачать документ, всё отлично работает, но попытавшись скачать аудио, вылазиет данная ошибка:     file_id = ms.document.file_id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'


Код:
`@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def download(ms: types.Message):
    file_id = ms.document.file_id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    await bot.download_file(file_path, "123.mp3")`

Comment: Думаю, вместо `document` в `message` нужно обращаться к другому полю, соответствующему аудио. Попробуйте `message.voice.file_id` либо `message.audio.file_id`. Обновил ответ для `voice`. А так, для учета обоих разом можно попробовать так: `obj = message.voice or message.audio` и `file_id = obj.file_id`

Comment: да, но как тогда отпралять этот файл опять пользователю с пк?
Такой код у меня вышел, но он не работает:

`@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def contents(ms: types.Message):
    file_id = ms.voice.file_id
    file = await bt.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    await bt.download_file(file_path, "file.mp3")
    audio = open('file.mp3', 'w')
    await bt.send_audio(chat_id=ms.from_user.id, audio=audio)`

Comment: При отправке, файл открывайте в режиме бинарного чтения: `open('file.mp3', 'rb')`